# Callback with Decorator or Parameter in Python?

Tags: python, callback

I'm designing an API. What's preferred using

```
@event1
def event_callback():
     print "wooop"
```

or something like:

```
def event_callback():
    print "wooop"


event1(callback=event_callback)
```

Comment: Using a decorator is the pythonic way of wrapping functions.

Answer (score 0):

The two alternatives are entirely equivalent. Decorator syntax was introduced because particularly for long functions it was easy to miss the decoration call following the definition, so you should use a decorator.